# How do I implement recursion to this python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

```
def recurse( aList ):
    matches = [ match for match in action if "A" in match ]
    uses = " ".join(matches)
    return f"Answer: { aList.index( uses )"
```

This is the non recursive method. I just couldn't figure out how to implement recursion in regards of lists.
Output should be `Answer: n uses.`
Can anybody help.

Comment: What does a value of `aList` look like? Is it (potentially) a nested list?

Comment: aList = ["Eat", "Eat. Run", "Play.", "Drive. A"]

Comment: so output should be ```3 uses``` in this case

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a bad fit for this problem in Python, because lists aren' really recursive data structures. But you could write the following:

```
def recurse(aList):
   if not aList:
       return 0
   return ("A" in aList[0]) + recurse(aList[1:])
```

Nothing in an empty list, by definition, contains `"A"`. Otherwise, determined if `"A"` is in the first element of the list, and add 1 or 0 as appropriate (remember, `bool`s are `int`s in Python) to the number of matches in the rest of the list.

The recursive function should only deal with the count itself; let the caller of the recursive function put the count into a string:

```
print("Answer: {recurse(aList)} uses"}
```